# Special font for only some symbols

Tags: math-mode, fonts, symbols, typography, math-operators

Is there a way to use `\usepackage{newtxmath}` only for `\sum`, `\int` and `\lambda` and just normal settings for all other symbols?

thanks.

Comment: maybe have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font

Comment: It is funny i followed a guide there and it worked but when i change the sum and integration sign it also changes the infinity sign. It seems there is no way to get both `mathabx` for `sum` and `int` but `ams` for `infty`. But thanks for the link.